# Newly defined action type not showing up in my own news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created a new action type for my Facebook app.  I followed the instructions that were available on the Facebook tutorial:

[http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial][1]

I have successfully set everything up, including a page that has all the Meta tags per post, etc.  In fact, when I publish the action from my Facebook app, I can see the action in my Activity Log.

However, it is not showing up in my own Newsfeed, or on my own Wall.

Is there anything I can do to debug what is going on?

Comment: did you have a resolution for this? I m having the same problem.